# Como carregar dados de um usuário especifico do mysql no xcode?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, xcode

Meu código esta funcionando, estou recebendo os dados que preciso, mas tenho que escrever o email do usuário que quero os dados no meu arquivo php. Queria receber os dados do usuário que o email for digitado em um textField no meu projeto. Como poderia fazer isso?

Meu arquivo php:

```
<?php

$servername = "*****";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";

// Criar conexao
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Queria pegar os dados do email que escrevi no textField, e para funcionar tenho que escrever o email diretamente no código   
    $sql = "SELECT id, nome, email, cpf, senha FROM usuario_log where email = 'albino@peggou.com.br'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultado = array("status" => "0", "id" => $row["id"], "nome" => $row["nome"], "email" => $row["email"], "cpf" => $row["cpf"], "senha" => $row["senha"]);
        }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }
    echo json_encode($resultado);

        $conn->close();
?>
```

Meu arquivo .m, recebo os dados no meu Log.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://peggou.com.br/dados.php"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSString *statusUser = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSString *idUser = [json objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *nomeUser = [json objectForKey:@"nome"];
    NSString *emailUser = [json objectForKey:@"email"];
    NSString *cpfUser = [json objectForKey:@"cpf"];
    NSString *senhaUser = [json objectForKey:@"senha"];
    NSLog(@"\n Status: %@,\n ID: %@,\n Nome: %@,\n E-mail: %@,\n CPF: %@,\n Senha: %@ \n", statusUser, idUser, nomeUser, emailUser, cpfUser, senhaUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
NSData * dadosBrutos=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://peggou.com.br/dados.php"]];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dadosBrutos options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];
NSString *statusUser = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
NSString *idUser = [json objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *nomeUser = [json objectForKey:@"nome"];
NSString *emailUser = [json objectForKey:@"email"];
NSString *cpfUser = [json objectForKey:@"cpf"];
NSString *senhaUser = [json objectForKey:@"senha"];
NSLog(@"\n Status: %@,\n ID: %@,\n Nome: %@,\n E-mail: %@,\n CPF: %@,\n Senha: %@ \n", statusUser, idUser, nomeUser, emailUser, cpfUser, senhaUser);
```

Comment: Valew, mas como faço para passar a informação do meu textField para o arquivo php, e como altero o meu php para que ele pegue essa informação do meu textfield para procurar, pois no meu arquivo atual eu escrevi o email diretamente no php para procurar, queria que ele procurasse pelo email que escrevi no meu textfield

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://peggou.com.br/dados.php?email=%@", textfield.text];
 NSData * dadosBrutos=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];